# Where and for what does Sharepoint use x-sharepoint-uc objects?

Tags: 2013

As an example, in calendar view pop-ups, the following object is added to the DOM by Sharepoint:

```
<object id="application/x-sharepoint-uc" type="application/x-sharepoint-uc" width="0" height="0" style="visibility: hidden;"></object>
```

What is it for and where are these elements used?

Comment: I believe it is part of the NameCtrl component that handles things like Lync presence, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thank you for comment @PirateEric, any rough clue is a good start.